# Is there any binary diff tool for android apk special for android apk file?

Tags: android, binary-diff

when trying to reduce the apk file size when updating, someone suggest to use `bsdiff` to make binary patch and merge the patch on client side. But I think this is a common binary diff tool and we can get smaller patch file like `chrome` do using [Courgette](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette), which working for `exe` file and get a more smaller patch file.

Is there any tool like `Courgette`? And if not, why don't Google develop some tool like it for us android developer?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play already automatically does [incremental](http://androidcommunity.com/google-play-store-incremental-smart-app-updates-now-live-20120816/) [updates](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/08/16/google-flips-the-switch-on-smart-app-updates-in-the-play-store-video/) as of August 2012, as announced at [Google I/O 2012](http://www.engadget.com/2012/06/27/google-brings-incremental-app-updates-to-android-added-encrypti/). No work is required on the developer's side.

Comment: Thx, @ianhanniballake we already know Google's smart update, but for some reason I want to update my app through my own server other than Google Play. So I wander how can I find some tool like Google Play doing?

Answer (score 1):

DiffTool from 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.difftool
can compare the content of APK files.

Answer (score 0):

The following tools might help:

1. [pkgdiff](https://lvc.github.io/pkgdiff/): It should support APK comparing according to its [git history](https://github.com/lvc/pkgdiff/pull/26), but it always returns UNCHANGE when comparing APKs in my case.
2. [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) + [pkgdiff](https://lvc.github.io/pkgdiff/): Work for code only. Using dex2jar to convert apk to jar, and pkgdiff to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

google diff&patch tool for apk(zip) file: https://github.com/google/archive-patcher
a File-By-File diff , used for apk store;
another tool for self apk:  https://github.com/sisong/ApkDiffPatch